# SQLite -Complex SELECT with multiple joins

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join

I have the following example tables with the respective columns:

```
PEOPLE: PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, GUARDIAN_ID

STATUS: PERSON_ID, STATUS
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
PEOPLE:
    2345, George, Foreman, null
    4567, Joseph, Galagar, 2345
    5632, Jenner, Shooter, 2345

STATUS:
    2345, DISPATCHED
    4567, PENDING
    5632, PENDING
```

Given the above, I wish to retrieve `PERSON_ID` from `PEOPLE` where `FIRST_NAME` is 'George', also the `STATUS` of those people from `STATUS`, and lastly the number of children each of these people has (in other words count on `PEOPLE` where the `PERSON_ID` is the `GUARDIAN_ID`).

How would I do this? I'm extremely rusty in this area. Its a bad example but should help with my actual problem.

Given the above, I should get the following result:

```
2345, DISPATCHED, 2
```

Comment: Provide some sample data. It will help.

Comment: Can you also provide some sample data?

Comment: Are you try my answer. Is it useful or it make any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE(PERSON_ID INT, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(25), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25), GUARDIAN_ID INT);

INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES(2345, 'George', 'Foreman', null);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES(4567, 'Joseph', 'Galagar', 2345);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES(5632, 'Jenner', 'Shooter', 2345);

CREATE TABLE STATUS(PERSON_ID INT, STATUS VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES(2345, 'DISPATCHED');
INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES(4567, 'PENDING');
INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES(5632, 'PENDING');
```

Using the Query, we get the result:

```
SELECT P.PERSON_ID
    ,MAX(S.STATUS)STATUS
    ,MAX(D.Counts)[No of Children]
FROM PEOPLE P
JOIN STATUS S ON S.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID
JOIN(SELECT GUARDIAN_ID, COUNT(1)Counts FROM PEOPLE GROUP BY GUARDIAN_ID) D ON D.GUARDIAN_ID = P.PERSON_ID
WHERE P.FIRST_NAME = 'George'
GROUP BY P.PERSON_ID
```

**Output:**

```
PERSON_ID   STATUS      No of Children
2345        DISPATCHED  2
```

Check this in the [#SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e639f/1)

Comment: @pnizzle, Fine. I hope the above answer will work. Try that, if any problem then write it in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

or to make it simpler and save a nested select,

```
select p.PERSON_ID, max(s.STATUS) as status, 
sum (case when kids.person_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as num_children
from PEOPLE p
left join PEOPLE kids on kids.GUARDIAN_ID = p.PERSON_ID
join STATUS s on s.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID
where p.FIRST_NAME = 'George'
group by p.PERSON_ID
```